# Facebook IOS app in and outs

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I need some help regarding the ios App, i want to know that how facebook app is rendering its pages, is it UIWebview or something else, is they are just rendering the HTML5 page by using UIwebview or its Custom UIViews. So if they are Custom UIViews how they manage the auto populating data mechanism.

Is there anybody, who can enlighten the in and outs of facebook ios app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The older version of the facebook application uses `UIWebView` to display content. According to the new version, it now uses native views and gets the data from facebook via an API.

Comment: so what about that autoloading, how they achieve that, its like ajax request and populating div...am i wrong?

Comment: @Shahrukh no there is no HTML in the new facebook, it is all UIViews that are populated from API calls.